# Extracting data based on lat-long range using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have data on climate and was able to view it in QGIS. It shows me a map of the world with black/white color that's lighter or darker based on the factor my data was measuring. Since the data is for the whole world, it's really big and I can't open it on a data analysis site that was required of me.

Is there a way to limit the data to a certain lat-long range? (my data is lat-long coordinates with inf).

Could one search for NY or Mexico in QGIS and just get the data points for that region?

If this is not possible to make the data set smaller, would I just need to get data that's specifically for those places to start with?

Answer (score 1):

Most interactive approach would be:

1. Zoom in to the area you want to cut
2. Open *Clipper* tool `Raster | Extraction | Clipper`
3. Choose your climate raster as `Input file (raster)`
4. Name the output filename in `Output file`
5. While keeping Clipping mode as `Extent` (checked), use your mouse to draw rectangle which defines the Extent. Modify `x` and `y` if you need to specify corners.
6. Click on `[OK]` button.

Comment: Ok that helps. Follow up question...So I had the output file saved as a tif file. Then converted that into .XYZ file (so that I can convert it to a .txt file). The saved .XYZ file shows up on the left side panel where my tif file is too, but beneath the tif file name, there are latitude and longitude values, but under the .xyz file's name it says "nan" instead. What does this mean and will my .XYZ file still hold data or is it corrupted?

Comment: @Anna I don't think values you are looking in the layer panel are latitude/longitude values, but cell values. The nan is probably suggesting you have somehow missed setting its CRS while saving it (either tif or xyz).